# Magento - size, color and stock

Tags: magento

I have a tshirt with 5 colors [white(2), grey(5), blue(3), green(2), black(7)] and 6 sizes (XS, S, M, L, XL, XXL)

Do I have to create 30 child-products to have this working? or is there a magento backend where i can create just one image and then have the values enter in a tabular format? nice and easy.

Comment: use configure products

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Configurable product then you need create simple product with all attribute combination.

There are some paid extension that will make this job easy

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/configurable-products-pro.html

If you do not want to manage the stock then you can use **Custom Option** for this also.

Comment: Thank You. So either way, i still have to create 30 simple products? Or can i add one product and use this extension to have it working the way i want?

Comment: is this the same as http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/easy-configurable-product-matrix.html